# On the notation for doesn't divide

Tags: notation, divisibility

Let $a,b,c$ be positive integers such that $a,b$ does not divide $c$.

I am aware that $a\nmid c$ and $b\nmid c$ is one way of representation.

I was wondering if $a,b\nmid c$ is a valid notation?

Comment: $a, b \nmid c$ is ambiguous. It looks are "$a$ comma $b \nmid c$.

Comment: I believe the same. Are you familiar with any other way to represent this?

Comment: The best is to write with words.

Comment: @RAHUL I think there is no other notation, maybe there exist other notation and I don't know.  But I agree with LL 3.14  that the best way is to write in words.

Comment: I see no problem with this notation. What else should it mean as that neither $a$ nor $b$ divides $c$ ?

Comment: I don't see that is much different from writing something like $s,t\in S$.

Comment: Yes, it is common notation, as is $\,a,b\mid c.\,$ But there is a slight risk it might be misread as the negation of that, i.e. $\,{\rm not}\, (a,b \mid c),\,$ i.e. $\, a\nmid c\,$ $\color{#c00}{\rm or}$  $\,b\nmid c.\ \ $

Comment: If it will be quickly clear from the context what your intended interpretation should be, it is fine to use it freely. But if you think people might be confused, offer a quick clarification the first time you use it (e.g., "$a,b\nmid c$ (i,e., $a\nmid c, b\nmid c$)") , and then you can use it freely thereafter.